# Parse a graph url to get route (users, places)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have the following code in C# to make a graph call:

```
public async Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetResponseAsync(string s)
{            

    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
        new QueryOption("$search", "")
    };

    return await graphServiceClient
                        .Users // or .Places
                        .Request(queryOptions)
                        .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                        .Filter("")
                        .Select("")
                        .OrderBy("")                        
                        .GetAsync();
    });
}
```

some examples of string s are:

"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"

"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room"

how do I parse this string so that I can get ***users*** or ***places***:

and run _graphServiceClient.Users or await _graphServiceClient.Places accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution can be to check if string contains users or places.

Then you need two different methods because for users the result will be `IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage` and for places `IGraphServicePlacesCollectionPage`.

Example

```
public async Task GetResponseAsync(string s)
{
    if (string.Contains("users")
    {
        var users = await GetUsersAsync(s);
    }
    else if(string.Contains("places")
    {
        var places = await GetPlacesAsync(s);
    }
}

public async Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUsersAsync(string s)
{            

    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
        new QueryOption("$search", "")
    };
    
    return await graphServiceClient
                        .Users
                        .Request(queryOptions)
                        .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                        .Filter("")
                        .Select("")
                        .OrderBy("")                        
                        .GetAsync();
}

public async Task<IGraphServicePlacesCollectionPage> GetPlacesAsync(string s)
{            

    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
        new QueryOption("$search", "")
    };

    var roomUrl = graphServiceClient        
                 .Places
                .AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.room");
    return await new GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest(roomUrl, graphServiceClient, queryOptions)
                .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                .Filter("")
                .Select("")
                .OrderBy("")
                .GetAsync();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! On running the code you suggested to get places, I see an error mentioned in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679179/notacceptable-error-when-calling-graph-api-from-c-sharp. And it suggests a solution.How do I update the code to use that solution and  add query option, header, filter, search, order by? Any suggestions?

Comment: @user989988 Check updated question how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quick question though - is there a way to parse the value microsoft.graph.room from the graph url string and pass it to the function instead of hard coding it?